# Asymptotic bound of some number theoretic function

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, asymptotics

I asked this in stack exchange but did not get anything so I am posting it here.

I am self-studying asymptotic behavior of some number theoretic function and the following question comes up.

Let $n$ be a natural number having prime factorization $p_1^{k_1}p_2^{k_2}\cdots p_r^{k_r}$.
Let $\tau:\mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$ defined by $\tau(n) = \prod_{i=1}^r(k_i+1)$. Then the literature says that $\forall \epsilon >0 ~\tau(n) = o(n^\epsilon)$ (see [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1406.3698)).

Now define $f:\mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$ by $f(n) = \prod(k_i+1)$ where the product runs over all those $i$ such that $p_i \equiv 1 \pmod 3$. Then what will be the asymptotic order of $f$? can we have some function $g(n)$ such that $f(n) = O(g(n))$?

I really appreciate any help you can provide.

Comment: It should be essentially the same. The bound that you quoted for $\tau(n)$ is of course an upper bound for $f(n)$ since $f(n)\le\tau(n)$. On the other hand, $f(n)=\tau(n)$ for those $n$ that are a product of primes of the form $6j+1$.

Comment: The stackexchange post is https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4605223/asymtotic-bound-of-some-number-theoritic-function

Comment: 'Can we have some function $g(n)$ such that $f(n)=O(g(n))$?' -- sure, just take $g=f$. If you're interested in explicit $g$s: as Anthony Quas explains, $g(n)=n^{\varepsilon}$ works for any $\varepsilon>0$. More precisely, S. Wigert proved that, for any given $\varepsilon>0$, $\tau(n) <\exp( (\log 2 + \varepsilon)\log n/ \log \log n))$ holds for all $n\ge N_{\varepsilon}$.

Comment: @OfirGorodetsky For the OP's function $f(n)$, the constant $\log 2$ in Wigert's bound surely can be decreased. I guess to $(\log 2)/2$, but I have not checked this formally.

Comment: @GHfromMO Perhaps surprisingly, the constant cannot be improved. Taking $n = \prod_{p \le x, \, p \equiv 1 \bmod 3} p=e^{x(1+o(1))/2}$, we have $\tau(n) = 2^{\pi(x;3,1)} = 2^{(1+o(1))x/(2\log x)} = 2^{(1+o(1) \log n/\log \log n}$, so $\exp((\log 2)\log n/\log \log n)$ is a lower bound for infinitely many $n$.

Comment: @OfirGorodetsky Thanks for your valuable comment. I should add (as a curiosity) that Wigert's original proof used the PNT. However, one can prove Wigert's bound without the PNT (or even without unique factorization), see e.g. https://users.renyi.hu/~gharcos/wigert4.pdf

Comment: @GHfromMO Thanks for sharing this cool note! Quite surprising that no unique factorization is needed (and this hints towards a generalization to number fields). Regarding OP's question, I would expect that a minor improvement (over $\tau(n)$) will appear in a lower order term in the exponent (that is not captured in Wigert's estimate, but was studied by Guy Robin it seems).

Comment: Let me also add that for the lower bound on $\tau(n)$ (or $f(n)$) one also does not need PNT, rather that $\pi(x) =x^{1+o(1)}$ (or $\pi(x;3,1)=x^{1+o(1)}$).

Comment: Thank you. I am just curious to know that does there exists any function which is asymptotically equal to $f$?